# Java: 2D Array Initialization to Null

Tags: java, arrays, null, 2d

I just wanted to check if my 2D-array initialization to null is correct in my following code.

```
protected Pixel[][] pixels;

protected PPMImage();
{
  pixels = null;
}
```

Comment: Put breakpoints in your compiler and see for yourself....

Comment: @ryekayo I'm compiling my program regularly using javac command in Ubuntu, how would I go on about doing that?

Comment: You need a compiler like Netbeans or Eclipse to put in breakpoints. But when you add a breakpoint in your method, it will confirm that the local variable is actually null. Based on your code though, your variable is uninitialized so it should already be set to null

Answer (score 1):

Yes 2D array can be initialized to null.
You wont get any compiler error or runtime error. Unless you try to retrieve something from this null array.
you can refer this link too : http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/multi-dimensional_arrays.html
Yes it will be better for you to debug and see such things . Debugging is easy with NetBeans ,Intellij or Eclipse . Still with simple java too you can debug program using jdb command. Read more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html